# Xanthoproteic test for phenylalanine

Tags: analytical-chemistry, amino-acids

I read on the net that phenylalanine gives a negative result with xanthoproteic test and the reason that was given was that the benzene ring is deactivated and hence the extent of nitration is very less.

What I dont understand is that isn't the benzene ring in phenylalanine actually activated through hyperconjugation from the $\ce{CH2}$ group of $\beta$-carbon and hence shouldn't it give positive results with the xanthoproteic test?

Comment: Phenylalanine can react with HNO3, but is less reactive then aromatic aminoacids.

Comment: that's exactly my question... why is it less reactive than other amino acids  even though the ring is activated through hyperconjugation?